# Dynamically updating a list from select input

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

On my page I have a list of all quotes entered into the database. I want to be able to select a user from a drop down box so that once that user is selected, the list of quotes gets updated so that it shows only quotes made by that user.

The trouble I have is I'm not well versed in JavaScript which I believe is how most would solve this problem. I already have the code that updates the list based on the user I just don't understand how to use the JavaScript to update the list dynamically.

A brief outline of my code:

**Controller**

```
if quoted_by = "all"
  # Show every quote
else
  # Show quotes only made by user
end
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="msQuotedBy">
    <b>Filter by Initials: </b>
    <%= select(:msQuotedBy, :select, ['all'] + @initials.collect {|p| [p, p]}, {:selected => @quoted_by}) %>
</span>
```

**JavaScript**, right now my JavaScript updates a calendar on the page dynamically just fine using the following code, but what should I do to update the list of quotes?

```
$('#msQuotedBy_select').change ->
    $('#msCalendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents')
```

The Controller obviously isn't right but that's how the logic plays out in my head. How do I use the `('#msQuotedBy_select')` value to update the list like I do the calendar?

Answer (score 1):

I'll probably use an AJAX call to an specific action in the controller, in that action retrieve the list of quotes from the user, and respond with a `.js.erb` file. In this file do something like:

```
<% html_content = j render(partial: 'a_partial_with_the_quotes', locals: { quotes: @user_quotes }) %>
$('#yourListOfQuotesContainer').html("<%= html_content %>);
```

Or something like that (I have not tested this, there are probably mistakes in the code, but that's the general idea)

Comment: How do I call a specific action in controller by using AJAX?

Comment: Just make the ajax request to the URL that is routed to your action. [See](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#an-introduction-to-ajax)